# Как добавить к пагинации переключение по стрелкам

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const items = [{
    title: 'Pagination1',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination2',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination3',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination4',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination5',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination6',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination7',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination8',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination9',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination10',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination11',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination12',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination13',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination14',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination15',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination16',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination17',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination18',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination19',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination20',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination21',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination22',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination23',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination24',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
];
let block = document.querySelector('#block');
let pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination__list');
let prevPage = document.querySelector('.pagination__arrow_prev');
let nextPage = document.querySelector('.pagination__arrow_next');
let notesOnPage = 4;

let countOfItems = Math.ceil(items.length / notesOnPage);

let paginationItem = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= countOfItems; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add('pagination__item');
  pagination.appendChild(li);
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = i;
  li.appendChild(span);
  paginationItem.push(span);
}
let active;
showPage(paginationItem[0]);
for (let item of paginationItem) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showPage(this);
  });
}

function showPage(item) {
  if (active) {
    active.classList.remove('_active')
  }
  active = item;
  item.classList.add('_active');


  let pageNum = +item.innerHTML;

  let start = (pageNum - 1) * notesOnPage;
  let end = start + notesOnPage;
  let notes = items.slice(start, end);

  block.innerHTML = '';
  for (let note of notes) {
    let blockItem = document.createElement('div');
    blockItem.classList.add('block__item');
    block.appendChild(blockItem);

    let blockTitle = document.createElement('h2');
    blockTitle.classList.add('block__title');
    blockTitle.innerHTML = note.title;
    blockItem.appendChild(blockTitle);

    let blockImg = document.createElement('img');
    blockImg.classList.add('block__img');
    blockImg.src = note.img;
    blockImg.alt = '';
    blockItem.appendChild(blockImg);
  }
}
```

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}

.block__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  padding: 5px;
}

.block__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination__arrow_prev {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__arrow_prev:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -15px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 15px 30px 15px 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55));
}

.pagination__arrow_next {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__arrow_next:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -15px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-style: solid;
  filter: drop-shadow(-10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55));
}

.pagination__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 20px;
}

.pagination__item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-radius: 22px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.pagination__item span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__item span._active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.pagination__link {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3b3b3b;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  // .pagination__arrow
  &__arrow {
    &_prev {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: -15px;
        left: -50px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-width: 15px 30px 15px 0;
        border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) transparent transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        filter: drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55));
      }
    }
    &_next {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: -15px;
        right: -50px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-width: 15px 0 15px 30px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
        border-style: solid;
        filter: drop-shadow(-10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55));
      }
    }
  }
  // .pagination__list
  &__list {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0 20px;
  }
  // .pagination__item
  &__item {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
    border-radius: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
    //&._active {
    //  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, .55);
    //}
    span {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 22px;
      cursor: pointer;
      &._active {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, .55);
      }
    }
  }
  &__link {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block" id="block"></div>
<div class="pagination" id="pagination">
  <div class="pagination__arrow pagination__arrow_prev"></div>
  <ul class="pagination__list">
  </ul>
  <div class="pagination__arrow pagination__arrow_next"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас уже все функции присутствуют. Нужно лишь добавить обработчики на стрелки и передавать нужные объекты:

```js
const items = [{
    title: 'Pagination1',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination2',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination3',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination4',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination5',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination6',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination7',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination8',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination9',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination10',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination11',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination12',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination13',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination14',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination15',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination16',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination17',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination18',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination19',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination20',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination21',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
  {
    title: 'Pagination22',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination23',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  }, {
    title: 'Pagination24',
    img: 'img/icons/loading.gif'
  },
];
let block = document.querySelector('#block');
let pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination__list');
let prevPage = document.querySelector('.pagination__arrow_prev');
let nextPage = document.querySelector('.pagination__arrow_next');
let notesOnPage = 4;

let countOfItems = Math.ceil(items.length / notesOnPage);

let paginationItem = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= countOfItems; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.classList.add('pagination__item');
  pagination.appendChild(li);
  let span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = i;
  li.appendChild(span);
  paginationItem.push(span);
}
let active;
showPage(paginationItem[0]);
for (let item of paginationItem) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    showPage(this);
  });
}

function showPage(item) {
  if (active) {
    active.classList.remove('_active')
  }
  active = item;
  item.classList.add('_active');


  let pageNum = +item.innerHTML;

  let start = (pageNum - 1) * notesOnPage;
  let end = start + notesOnPage;
  let notes = items.slice(start, end);

  block.innerHTML = '';
  for (let note of notes) {
    let blockItem = document.createElement('div');
    blockItem.classList.add('block__item');
    block.appendChild(blockItem);

    let blockTitle = document.createElement('h2');
    blockTitle.classList.add('block__title');
    blockTitle.innerHTML = note.title;
    blockItem.appendChild(blockTitle);

    let blockImg = document.createElement('img');
    blockImg.classList.add('block__img');
    blockImg.src = note.img;
    blockImg.alt = '';
    blockItem.appendChild(blockImg);
  }
}

prevPage.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (active.parentElement.previousElementSibling) {
    showPage(active.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span'));
  }
});
nextPage.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (active.parentElement.nextElementSibling) {
    showPage(active.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector('span'));
  }
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 50px;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}

.block__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  padding: 5px;
}

.block__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #9c9c9c;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination__arrow_prev {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__arrow_prev:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -15px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 15px 30px 15px 0;
  border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55));
}

.pagination__arrow_next {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__arrow_next:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -15px;
  right: -50px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 15px 0 15px 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-style: solid;
  filter: drop-shadow(-10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55));
}

.pagination__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0 20px;
}

.pagination__item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  border-radius: 22px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.pagination__item span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pagination__item span._active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.pagination__link {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #3b3b3b;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  // .pagination__arrow
  &__arrow {
    &_prev {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: -15px;
        left: -50px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-width: 15px 30px 15px 0;
        border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) transparent transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        filter: drop-shadow(10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55));
      }
    }
    &_next {
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      &:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: -15px;
        right: -50px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-width: 15px 0 15px 30px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
        border-style: solid;
        filter: drop-shadow(-10px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55));
      }
    }
  }
  // .pagination__list
  &__list {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0 20px;
  }
  // .pagination__item
  &__item {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
    border-radius: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .55);
    //&._active {
    //  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, .55);
    //}
    span {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 22px;
      cursor: pointer;
      &._active {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, .55);
      }
    }
  }
  &__link {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3b3b3b;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block" id="block"></div>
<div class="pagination" id="pagination">
  <div class="pagination__arrow pagination__arrow_prev"></div>
  <ul class="pagination__list"></ul>
  <div class="pagination__arrow pagination__arrow_next"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да точно! Спасибо!

Comment: Новая проблема. Не могу сообразить как добавить точки и скрыть часть цифр.  Подскажите идею

Comment: @СлаваГрачев: новая проблема не имеет ничего общего с текущим вопросом. Новая проблема - новый вопрос (а Вы ещё за этот не "расплатились" ✔ :-)

Comment: Все оплатил!) Извините!